# Is it possible to debug a core file originally produced by an executable which had symbols stripped?

Tags: c++, linux, coredump, crash-dumps

A core file was produced by a Release version of code (g++) which had symbols stripped.

Taking that same (SVN) version of code, I have modified the build options to include symbols.

Should I be able to debug that core file using the executable I've built which includes symbols? It doesn't appear I can, but just want to make sure it isn't something else I'm doing wrong.

```
bash-3.2$ gdb ./MyTest.53519 -c  ~/public_html/core.20375.MyTest 
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.0.1-42.el5)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /home/me/tmp/MyTest.53519...done.

warning: core file may not match specified executable file.
[New Thread 20388]
[New Thread 20389]
Reading symbols from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
Core was generated by `./MyTest -np1 -p1'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007f99c19b39e0 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f99c19b39e0 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007f99bc438650 in ?? ()
#2  0x00007f99c19b58cf in ?? ()
#3  0x00007f9994008880 in ?? ()
#4  0x00007f99b8013080 in ?? ()
#5  0x00007f99bc4386f0 in ?? ()
#6  0x00007f99bc438b00 in ?? ()
#7  0x00007f99bc438810 in ?? ()
#8  0x00007f99c19aa489 in ?? ()
```

Comment: IMHO, I believe it is *possible*.  Maybe very difficult, but possible.  For example, debugging may be faster by creating an executable with debug symbols and using that executable than debugging an executable without symbols.  I hope you are really good at reading assembly code (human readable form) or machine code (the instruction numbers).

Comment: Do you have a *map* file that shows symbols and addresses?  You could look up the address in the map file to find the closest symbol or statement.

Comment: All beyond C++ standards! Get specific to your actual environment!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It's "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".

Comment: I think this warning from gdb says it all: `warning: core file may not match specified executable file.`.

Answer (score 3):

In theory it should work to reproduce symbols by building the program again. But it requires that you have exactly the same version of compiler, with exactly the same settings, same version of OS and same version of libraries, system headers, etc, and the OS doesn't do address randomization [or the debugger understands the address shuffling].

It does appear, however, that SOMETHING is missing in that chain of "If ... and ... " that I listed above - which means your stack and it's content isn't particularly meaningful.

You may want to do `x/1000zg $rsp` and see if the stack content looks more sane that way than the backtrace. You can always load your debug-symbol'd executable in a separate gdb instance, and use `disass 0x124213,+123` to disassemble what is at `0x123213` (and 123 bytes on) in that process.

Also, assuming you are not 100% certain of threads, try `info thread` to see what threads are about.

I don't envy you...

Comment: I think the thing to do, if you want to distribute stripped executables so that crackers can't leverage the debug information (or just to reduce download size), is to build once with maximum debug information, **keep the unstripped binary for yourself**, strip and distribute.  As long as you are debugging with the full binary that matches the stripped one, things should go better.

Answer (score 3):

I have had to do this and let me tell you it is not easy.

The method I ended up using was much like yours. I built a copy of the library with all of the same options, plus debugging symbols.

Then I looked into the core dump to find the crash location. I used gdb disassembly view to find the machine instructions and backed up until I found the function start.

Then I went into `objdump -dC` on the original library without symbols to find the matching location by searching for matching series of machine instructions. That gave me the offsets in the library.

Then I was able to go into the library built with debugging symbols and find the same function. It was usually in the same general area, although small shifts could happen because of random numbers used by the compiler. (Note: I later started using GCC's `-frandom-seed` option to force use of the SAME random numbers on each compile run. Read the docs. Must be a different seed for each source file.)

From there it was a matter of reading the disassembly to determine what had gone wrong. If the core dump said it crashed from reading a NULL pointer in register $r12 I had to figure from the debug symbol version where $r12 got its value.

After doing this a few times I changed the build system to use the same random seeds for every build and to build a debug symbol version from the start, which is stripped to produce the final binaries. All versions are stuffed into an SVN server to be pulled out as needed later. Although since each build has unique directory names a simple NFS directory would work just as well.